# Visual Studio integration with free SCM

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2010, git, mercurial

I am looking for TFS free alternatives to manage source code. I ve worked with CVS and SVN. I know GIT and Mercurial, but I still haven´t worked with them.

I would to use anyone of them integrated with Visual Studio, with the same ease which use TFS (Solution Explorer contextual menu, a dockable source explorer, etc).

Do you know free plugins to do this?

Comment: Once you get used to use Git from the command line, you don't try to find a plugin/add-in for VS anymore

Comment: Similarly to @Oscar, I'd suggest that integration with VS maybe isn't as big a deal as you might think. I'm not a command line guru, but I've got used to using an [external tool](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html), and I actually prefer it. It keeps the coding and 'bookwork' separate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would highly suggest using Mercurial.

With visual studio, there is a free plugin http://visualhg.codeplex.com/.

In addition, there is a windows shell package you can install called tortiseHG which makes it super easy to deal with Mercurial in windows. http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/

There are other plugins that you can use for SVN and GIT.

For GIT, you might use msysGIT, which again has nice shell integration features:
http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/

As well as visual studio extensions
http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/

For SVN, there is AnkhSVN http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/

If you havent used alot of SCM's, I would highly recommend trying out Mercurial. Distributed SCM's are quickly becoming the optimal way to deal with source control. It's just the right way to do things.

Here are a couple of resources to get you started if you are interested in Mercurial:

Excellent tutorial by Joel Spolsky:
http://hginit.com/

Thorough coverage of Mercurial features:
http://hgbook.red-bean.com/

Best of Luck.

Answer (score 3):

I use Mercurial with [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) which provides Explorer context menus and status icons and the [VisualHG](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/) plugin which provides Visual Studio integration and.

The level of integration with Visual Studio is not quite as slick as the level of integration that you get with TFS, nethertheless combined they make a very productive working environment.  In fact in certain areas I prefer the integration over the TFS integration - in particular I find the TFS explorer a tad cumbersome as it requires that an instance of VS be running.  In contrast the TortoiseHg repository explorer is very lightweight and quick to start.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Git Extesions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/). It has nice windows gui and visual studio plugin. It works with cygwiin and msysgit.

Comment: Seconded. Git Extensions integrates really well with VS, and also includes standalone GUI tools and a command-line shell (by bundling cygwin and msysgit).

Answer (score 1):

I used "AnkhSVN" (http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) plugin to access SVN. Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done many things with GIT at the moment, but if you are familiar with SVN and are working under Windows you may have found TortoiseSVN yet. I recommend to give [TortoiseGIT](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) a try.

In fact I do not see any need for a tight integration into MS Visual Studio. I'm currently working with Access and (shame on me) Visual Basic 6, and there is no Subversion integration at all. Checkin/out, viewing the logs, branching and many other things work quite well under TortoiseSVN.

The last time I used this integration was Visual SourceForge, which by default provides file locks. This made it necessary to get a good integration. As SVN and GIT don't provide locks in the first place, I prefer to use a stand-alone client.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tortoise SVN and Visual Studio, I highly recommend [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) Visual Studio plugin. It is not free, but it's well worth the money.

Comment: plugin is really nice, but svn can't compete with mercurial and git.